# Browsing Stellar's history archive

Tags: history

From what I understand, Stellar.org keeps the history of their core nodes [here](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/history.stellar.org/).

I can click that URL and see an XML-formatted file list in my browser. Which is nice. 
However, to get a better feel for the data and dig a little deeper, I'm looking for a convenient way to browse through it.

I have tried [Transmit](https://panic.com/transmit/), but it keeps asking me for an access key. Presumably I'm using it wrong.

Do any of you:
 - have a convenient way of browsing Stellar's archive?
 - have been able to get Transmit working for this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im using the [aws command line tool](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_IL&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=command_line_b&sc_content=aws_cli_e&sc_detail=aws%20cli&sc_category=command_line&sc_segment=161196261488&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=IL&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!161196261488!e!!g!!aws%20cli&ef_id=WYlkMAAAAdFAaYpZ:20180429120202:s)

For example to see the contents of the archive

```
aws s3 --no-sign-request ls s3://history.stellar.org/
```

Or to look at a specific folder in the testnet archives

```
aws s3 --no-sign-request ls s3://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_001/transactions/00/60/a1/
```

Comment: That's a great tip, I didn't think of that yet. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried it out and works beautifully :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the [stellar-archivist](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/tools/stellar-archivist#dumping-an-xdr-file-from-an-archive-as-json) tool?

The provided link shows an example of how to print a fetched archive file (ledger header, transactions, results, etc) as JSON in your terminal. Hope that helps!

Comment: I have, but thank you! I still need to get to the archive in question first and want to browse through it, but the archivist tool is a great resource.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to view archive data for Stellar is to run a [Stellar Core](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core) node with [`CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/admin.html#surviving-stellar-core-downtime). This will pull in all the archive data. You can get all the options for the configuration file from [here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_example.cfg) and [a sample config file from here](https://github.com/stellar/docs/blob/master/other/stellar-core-validator-example.cfg).

To easily view this data you can run a [Horizon](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/horizon) server on top of your stellar core instance and use the Horizon APIs to query any historical data that you need.

Comment: Thanks @stackcats, I appreciate the answer. It's not what I'm looking for however. That core will load the archive into its own bucket, as I understand it, putting me back on square one on how to browse an archive :)

Answer (score 1):

For **reading**, the preferred place to retrieve the SDF history archives is here:

- http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/
- http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/
- http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/

These are mirrored from S3 and cached on Cloudflare. The directories do not allow listing, so to browse, begin at the root file of the relevant archive (as [described in the docs](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/history.md#root-has)), e.g.

http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/.well-known/stellar-history.json

for the history archive of SDF's first validator.