# If stellar-core maintains the data, how to view the deleted data

Tags: stellar-core

stellar-core will automatic maintenance.Maintenance code:main/Maintainer.cpp.
it will delete old data in maintenance process,how to view the deleted data?

Answer (score 1):

Stellar's blockchain history isnt preserved inside the core's database (or at least, it isnt necessarily saved there). Rather, the core uploads the history to some pre-set location, like an S3 bucket or wherever. The idea is that this place needs to be public, so other cores can read it if/when they start up.

Answer (score 0):

Stellar core can save old history in xdr files 
https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/history.md

Comment: Are you talking about `get` and `put` in the configuration file? `get` used to specify where to fetch the history archives  and  `put` used to specify where to  store the history archives .Is that so?

Comment: Yes, for example, you can check the stellar foundation files like this : https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/921/browsing-stellars-history-archive/958#958